# In my code, it shows the image, but it's inverted colors

Tags: python, opencv

So my code has inverted colors even though I didn't make it have inverted colors. I need help, thank you! I still don't get what I did wrong, if anyone could help that would be awesome.

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import cv2 as cv 
from google.colab.patches import cv2_imshow # for image display
from skimage import io
from PIL import Image
import matplotlib.pylab as plt 

image = io.imread("https://www.iheartradio.ca/image/policy:1.10300058:1575309830/UnitedST.png?f=default&$p$f=3b4677e")

height = image.shape[0]
width = image.shape[1]

print(width, "and", height)

cv2_imshow(image)

img_flip_lr = cv.flip(image, 1)
cv2_imshow(img_flip_lr)

img_flip_upsidown = cv.flip(image, 0)
cv2_imshow(img_flip_upsidown)

scale_percent = 50# percent of original size
width = int(image.shape[1] * scale_percent / 100)
height = int(image.shape[0] * scale_percent / 100)
dim = (width, height)

# resize image
resized = cv.resize(image, dim, interpolation = cv.INTER_AREA)
cv2_imshow(resized)
```

Comment: Don't mix libraries. You are using  `scikit-image` to read the image and `OpenCV` to display it. `scikit-image` uses the `RGB` color format while OpenCV uses `BGR`.

Comment: Well, you can mix libraries, just remember to convert the color space, see [cvtColor()](https://docs.opencv.org/master/d8/d01/group__imgproc__color__conversions.html#ga397ae87e1288a81d2363b61574eb8cab) for RGB to BGR conversion.

Answer (score 1):

OpenCV uses BGR as default colorspace.
After reading the image from source with is RGB, you can convert it by
`image = cv2.cvtColor(image, cv2.COLOR_RGB2BGR)`

Regards,
Andy